# One Form Control, Multiple Inputs, Disable Each Individually. Is This Possible?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms and have a form control "AccountStatus" that is a number from 0-2. I have three radio buttons that each correspond to these values and are tied to the same form control via `formControlName="AccountStatus"`.

I want to be able to disable one or more of these without affecting the others, but if I disable one then all get disabled. What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the code?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to make a custom component that implements ControlValueAccessor and change the [disabled] binding's behaviour in its template.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Thanks for the responses though.